# Sphinx wrong endianess

Tags: sphinx

Господа, второй день горит пукан пламенным батхертом, а причина этому следующая. Сие изрыгает Sphinx при пробном индексировании после установки. ОС Debian 6. Как исправить?  `USE_LITTLE_ENDIAN` делал и 0 и 1. Но результат неумолимо повторяется. Я в смятении.

```
Oops! It seems that sphinx was built with wrong endianess (cross-compiling?)
either reconfigure and rebuild, defining ac_cv_c_bigendian=no in the environment of ./configure script,
either ensure that '#define USE_LITTLE_ENDIAN = 1' in config/config.h
```